Auto differentiation with JAX in python and ForwardDiff.jl in Julia give matrices with different values but same structure. Are the results right?
Using ForwardDiff in Julia gives me the following values for 2 matrices


I have tried to use JAX to auto differentiate the same function in Python but I am getting
the following results for A and B respectively


Both results have the same structure but have different values. Are both results equivalent or is this incorrect?
PS. I have also tried a finite difference library (numdifftools) in the python version and its giving me the same results as JAX

Yes, you are right. For the past 2 days, I had missed that one of my parameter values was different in Python. Now both answers are the same. Thank you for your response. I am new to stackexchange, would you suggest that I delete this question as it was a trivial error on my part? If not, you could post this as an answer and I'll choose it

Glad I could help! I posted my comment as an answer.

I’m voting to close this question because this is an error on the user side with no benefit for the community.

Are you sure the implementations of the function that you wish to differentiate return the same results both in Julia and Python? That seems the first place to look for bugs.
